# Access Algolia REST API via JavaScript: CORS errors

Tags: javascript, cors, algolia

I am trying to access the Algolia REST API directly via JavaScript `fetch` request. I can successfully make the request in `curl`, but when translating to JavaScript I get CORS errors.

This is my code:

```
    const API_KEY = 'my_api_key';
    const APP_ID = 'my_app_id';
    const url = `https://${APP_ID}-dsn.algolia.net`;
    const query = 'my_query';
    const data = {
      params: `query=${query}&hitsPerPage=1`
    };

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Algolia-API-Key': API_KEY,
        'X-Algolia-Application-Id': APP_ID
      })
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

And these are the CORS errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my_app_id-dsn.algolia.net/. (Reason: CORS request external redirect not allowed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my_app_id-dsn.algolia.net/. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my_app_id-dsn.algolia.net/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I feel like there's something really obvious I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i mean... there are three error messages. Each one specifies something that is wrong with the request. (note that they're all pointing out flaws in the api, not your code.)

Comment: The api is not configured to be accessed via client-side javascript. Maybe you should consider not accessing it with client-side javascript.

Comment: I should have mentioned that Algolia supplies client-side libraries that access the API via client side JS, so I know it's possible. That's helpful to know it's nothing in my code per se, though. I'll try to look into how they configure their JS client.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is they pass it through something other than the rest api, or use some other method of passing the api key.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I was making a silly mistake. Algolia uses a different URL path for POST vs GET request, and either way I was using the wrong path.

For the record, the working code is exactly as above, except with this URL pattern

```
const url = `https://${APP_ID}-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/${MY_INDEX}/query`;
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Algolia JS client, it not only deals with these specifics, but also with retrying in case any of the three hosts are down. It’s available as the “algoliasearch” package on npm or via cdn.

Feel free to ask more info on what the API client does, I’m currently one of the maintainers.

Comment: I actually am using the algolia instantsearch library, but needed extra functionality not provided.

Comment: The API client instance is available when making custom widgets, which usage did you have?

Comment: Oh interesting, I couldn't figure out how to access that. I need to find the if the result of a query in a query suggestion appears in X other indices.

Comment: In that case I’d use helper.searchOnce multiple times, but worth investigating. Do you have a complete project to try out several strategies?

Answer (score -1):

Try using jsonp

```js
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: api_url,
  dataType: 'jsonp', //change the datatype to 'jsonp' works in most cases
  success: (res) => {
   console.log(res);
  }
})
```

Other way is to use some Proxy service. Here is one https://crossorigin.me/